Apply discounts grouped by product category to Woocommerce Cart
I need help with a code for Woocommerce.
I need to add a discount for each selected category in each product, and group it by each category:
For example:
I have 3 categories:

Category 1 -> Discount 20%
Category 2 -> Discount 10%
Category 3 -> Discount 5%

If I add a product from category 1, I would have to get the discount selected from that category.
And if I add a product from category 2, then the discount from that category applies.
The problem comes when you have products from different categories in the cart:
For example: -> Cart

Product A -> Category 1
Product B -> Category 2
Product C -> Category 1
Product D -> Category 3

Below the subtotal, I would have to add the discount grouped by categories and give me the discount for all the products in that category:
For example: -> Subtotal

Discount Category 1 -> The discount on all products in Category 1.
Discount Category 2 -> The discount of all products in Category 2
Discount Category 3 -> The discount of all products in Category 3

They have solved my problem with this code, in case someone needs it in the future.
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_product_category' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_product_category' ) ) {

    function wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_product_category( $cart ) {
        $fees = array(
            'cat1' => 10,
            'cat2' => 5,
            'cat3' => 3,
        );

        // Initialize an array to store the discounts grouped by category
        $category_discounts = array();

        // Loop through the cart items
        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $product_id = $values['product_id'];
            $product_price = $values['data']->get_price();
            $product_categories = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
            $quantity = $values['quantity'];

            // Check if the product has categories and there is no error
            if ( $product_categories && ! is_wp_error( $product_categories ) ) {
                foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
                    $category_slug = $product_category->slug;

                    // Check if the category has a defined discount
                    if ( ! empty( $fees[ $category_slug ] ) ) {
                        $discount_percentage = $fees[ $category_slug ];
                        $discount_amount = $product_price * $quantity * ($discount_percentage / 100);

                        // Accumulate the discount for the category
                        if ( ! isset( $category_discounts[ $category_slug ] ) ) {
                            $category_discounts[ $category_slug ] = 0;
                        }
                        $category_discounts[ $category_slug ] += $discount_amount;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Add the accumulated discounts as fees in the cart
        foreach ( $category_discounts as $category_slug => $discount_amount ) {
            $category_name = get_term_by( 'slug', $category_slug, 'product_cat' )->name;
            $fee_name = 'Discount (' . $fees[$category_slug] . '%): ' . $category_name;
            $cart->add_fee( $fee_name, -$discount_amount, false );
        }
    }
}


Not enough rep to comment on the OP, but reposting OP's self-answer in accordance with Stack Overflow's best practices (https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).
If OP properly adds a self-answer with the same content it should be upvoted instead of this.
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_product_category' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_product_category' ) ) {

    function wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_product_category( $cart ) {
        $fees = array(
            'cat1' => 10,
            'cat2' => 5,
            'cat3' => 3,
        );

        // Initialize an array to store the discounts grouped by category
        $category_discounts = array();

        // Loop through the cart items
        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $product_id = $values['product_id'];
            $product_price = $values['data']->get_price();
            $product_categories = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
            $quantity = $values['quantity'];

            // Check if the product has categories and there is no error
            if ( $product_categories && ! is_wp_error( $product_categories ) ) {
                foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
                    $category_slug = $product_category->slug;

                    // Check if the category has a defined discount
                    if ( ! empty( $fees[ $category_slug ] ) ) {
                        $discount_percentage = $fees[ $category_slug ];
                        $discount_amount = $product_price * $quantity * ($discount_percentage / 100);

                        // Accumulate the discount for the category
                        if ( ! isset( $category_discounts[ $category_slug ] ) ) {
                            $category_discounts[ $category_slug ] = 0;
                        }
                        $category_discounts[ $category_slug ] += $discount_amount;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Add the accumulated discounts as fees in the cart
        foreach ( $category_discounts as $category_slug => $discount_amount ) {
            $category_name = get_term_by( 'slug', $category_slug, 'product_cat' )->name;
            $fee_name = 'Discount (' . $fees[$category_slug] . '%): ' . $category_name;
            $cart->add_fee( $fee_name, -$discount_amount, false );
        }
    }
}

